# Isabelle: new axiom for undefined functions

Tags: isabelle

I am working on a theory where I use extensional functions defined in the Funcset theory quite heavily. I need to work with function valued functions where both the function, and the values are extensional. It is quite annoying that some of my lemmas fail because an `undefined` function does not map everything into `undefined`. So the goal

```
undefined x = undefined
```

is not provable. I can work around this using restrictions, but it would be much more elegant without those. Is it safe to add a new axiom:

```
axiomatization where 
  undefined_at [simp]: "undefined x = undefined"
```

? I am concerned about this because

1) I'm not sure if I should fiddle around with the logic like this.

2) After I add this axiom, for goals like " undefined \in A", nitpick produces the error : `Limit reached: too many nested axioms (256).`

3) The seemingly similarly innocent axiom

```
axiomatization where 
  at_undefined [simp]: "f undefined = undefined"
```

produces weird goals like "P ==> undefined" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constant `undefined` does not really model the mathematical notion of `undefined`. Rather does it denote not being specified, as I have explained in a [thread](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2013-September/msg00155.html) on the Isabelle mailing list.

[Back in 2008](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/2cf13a72e170/src/HOL/HOL.thy#l204), `undefined` actually was specified with the axiom `undefined x = undefined`, i.e., the function `undefined` maps everything to `undefined`. Soon, people realised that this was not what `undefined` should represent, because it restricted the function `undefined` to a constant function, which is not an arbitrary function at all. Adding this axiom does not make HOL unsound, but it severely restricts the generality of the what is proven, because `undefined` is used a lot by Isabelle's packages.

The other axiom `at_undefined` however leads to inconsistencies. As stated it means that every function `f` should be the identity on unspecified value `undefined`. Consider the type `bool` of Booleans. `undefined` must be either `True` or `False`. So if you take negation for `f`, then the axiom requires that `~ True = True` or `~ False = False`. Obviously, this is inconsistent with the specification of `op ~`, so the axiom is inconsistent.

Comment: Thank you, your reply was very helpful. It is good to know that `undefined_at` is safe and reasonable to add, but too specific for some applications. I'm going to define a new `undefined` (I'm tempted to call it `nothing`) with the stronger axiom and use that where I need to.

Comment: Actually, you do not need axioms. Define a type class `class nothing = fixes nothing` and instantiate it for the types you need. For the function type, use 
`instantiation "fun" :: (type, nothing) nothing begin`
`definition "nothing x = nothing"`
`instance ..`
`end`
If it is too cumbersome to instantiate all the types, you can also use unrestricted overloading, which is also safe.
`consts nothing :: 'a`
`overloading f == "nothing :: ('a ⇒ 'b)" begin`
`definition nothing_fun_def: "f (x :: 'a) = (nothing :: 'b)"`
`end`
With both approaches, you can add more equations for other types later on.